# The point of Linked Lists and Pointers in C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list, reference

I honestly need help understanding this. I'm a CS student and I'm at this huge mental road block on these topics because I just cant get past in my head why this is important/why we spend so much emphasis on this.

As far as pointers go why would you ever want to point to an object or variables address when you can just pass everything by reference? Is there a reason we can't just efficiently pass these things by reference instead of using pointers?

Also, why is deleting pointers or specifically deleting things on the heap not done automatically in C++? Why doesn't that just delete like everything else? Why isn't it just integrated into C++ just like everything else?

Comment: _"Why is there SO much emphasis and trouble put into the concept of building your own linked list with pointers instead of just using a list object from the standard library."_ Because it's a common task given by incompetent professors to do that for students probably.

Comment: You are asking too many questions and most of them are opinionated.

Comment: Why use a hand written linked list over the standard library linked list?

Why use pointers when you can pass by reference?

Why doesnt C++ deallocate the memory on the heap

Comment: I can see a benefit for teaching linked lists in a data structures class so that the students understand how things work instead of a black box.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually I think it is because they want to teach people to _learn_ stuff instead of just _use_ stuff.

Comment: @Justin In production code, you wouldn't in 99.99% of the time when you want a linked list (which is also pretty rare). It's pretty much just if `std::list` doesn't provide what you need (which is rare). In a class, you'd use it because there is value in truly understanding how things work

Comment: I am more irritated when academics teach `c` and call it `c++` or worse yet use a 25+ year old compiler.

Comment: I see Linked list as a combination of a weeder assignment (you either get it or you don't, and if you don't, nice knowing you) and an incredibly dense education. You probably learn more implementing a correct and efficient linked list than you do in any other classroom assignment.

Comment: @juanchopanza But not at beginner classes as done so often.

Comment: Unrelated, seeing Justin tagging Justin is kind of surreal.

Comment: How would you build a graph, "passing by reference" instead of using pointers?

Comment: A good way to learn about programming is to solve the same problems other people, who came before you, solved. Problems with well known solutions. At the end of the day what does it matter? Whatever you do needs to be hard to solve in order to make you develop the skills you need.

Comment: You are a CS student; computer languages (and libraries) are like carpenters tools (use the right tool for the job).  CS students are learning how to make these tools not just to use them.

Comment: One of the big problems of automatic management of dynamic allocations is when does this happen? How does this happen? [Does this happen?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203) C++ went with a different school of thought that treated memory just like it would any other resource. For example Java when you want a file closed on a schedule, you have to close it yourself. Why not carry this through and make all resources equal in the eyes of the Giver Of Data?

Comment: *"why go through so much trouble to discuss making your own linked lists"* - because it isn't about what you'll use; it's about learning how it works, and linked lists are a seemingly real come-to-Jesus moment for students these days (far more than they were three decades ago; believe me, when it was just one tiny part of a long arduous data structures curriculum). The purpose isn't so you can someday make your own; its learning about an architectural design; about how things *work*. No sugar coating it; if someone can't demonstrably wrap their head around linked lists, it doesn't bode well.

Comment: @Justin Just for the record, I have yet to see a student put together a working linked list in C++.  By working, I mean bug free, no memory leaks, has proper copy semantics, etc.  The only persons I have seen that put together a proper linked list in C++ are experienced coders.  So don't feel bad if you have trouble -- no student that I know of (maybe there is one out there) has completed this assignment (unless they got lots of help from experienced C++ folks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of going through these exercises is not to learn how to make linked lists per-se, but to learn how to *solve problems* and *implement code according to designs*. Don't forget that whatever you do in class is pretty much junk by definition, you're not going to roll that code out in an application, it's just an exercise for learning. You create these programs to *understand* and practice, not to create solutions.

The code you write to learn and explore is radically different from the code you write to actually solve problems. When trying to solve problems stay focused on the solution, try to avoid getting caught up with trying new things just for the sake of having fun. When learning try to avoid going too quickly to the solution, instead explore other approaches and weigh their advantages and drawbacks.

Now as to why C++ takes that approach, every language has a philosophy that dictates its design. In C++ that means you are 100% in charge of memory management, you have complete control. While this gives you incredible latitude in *how* you go about doing that, it also means it's an enormous responsibility.

If you want garbage collection you can get it, but you have to ask and you have to use things like the Standard Library containers or pointer wrappers.

A lot of modern C++ revolves around avoiding memory management altogether by focusing on a design that makes objects cheap to copy, by passing in things by reference whenever possible, and by leveraging the tools provided by the Standard Library to make manual memory management largely irrelevant. `new` is something you do out of desperation, not by design.

For more insight you might want to invest in some books that focus on [applying C++ strategically](https://www.aristeia.com/books.html).

Comment: What about pointers? Is there a reason you wouldn't just pass something by reference?

Comment: C++ introduced references fairly late into the game so there's a lot of C++ core code that requires pointers, plus you'll often need to interface with C code (e.g. `stdlib`) which is all about pointers. Sometimes pointers are the answer, but when you can, use references, especially `const` references. Newer iterations of the C++ standard have made big strides in terms of cleaning up the language and making it more reference friendly, but there's still some warts here and there.

Comment: @Justin References aren't nullable or re-bindable, so they aren't that useful for creating linked lists that can to stuff like grow, be spliced, have nodes inserted in the middle, etc.

Comment: @tadman C++ has always had references.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Ah, when the first C++ standard originated they were there, but they came after the class system was defined. What I mean by that is that `this` is a pointer because classes came *before* references.